# nginx rewrite part of url with ? mark

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm serving a website with nginx as a proxy for apache.
I have a problem with rewrite module.

`http://example.com/foo/bar/url?someparam=1&otherparam=2`

I need to rewrite from

/foo/bar/**url**?someparam=1&otherparam=2

to

/foo/bar/**url2**?someparam=1&otherparam=2

I found it problematic, since it's not `/foo/bar/url/someparam`, but it's only a part of text, i need to rewrite in dynamic url's.

I was trying:
`rewrite    ^(.*)url(.*)$    $1url2$2;` but i'm getting error 500 on that.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `rewrite` statement, the new URI also matches the regular expression pattern. This will cause a redirection loop that ends with a 500 response.

You need to make the regular expression more specific so that the new URI does not match.

Also, the `nginx` uses a normalised URI when processing `rewrite` statements, that does not include the `?` and the query string that follows it. So your statement could be simplified as follows:

```
rewrite ^(.*)url$ $1url1;
```

The `rewrite` directive will automatically append any `?` and query string in the original URI.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

The URI that